# backbone.js and google maps markers

Tags: google-maps, backbone.js

I am having trouble adding markers to a google map with backbone.

I created a jsfiddle for easier debugging...

http://jsfiddle.net/jLc53/3/

I think that the problem might have to do with the posts collection being empty when the map is rendered, but I am not sure.

I have an API that returns posts information, and each post has a latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue is that your API (appears to be using TastyPie) returns the array of results not as the root of the response, but as a sub-property.

Backbone Collections expect to receive an array of objects:

```
[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3}]
```

Your API returns:

```
{meta:{response metadata},objects:[{obj1},{obj2},{obj3}]}
```

The way to deal with that in Backbone Collections is to override the [`parse` function](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-parse) so that it returns an array of objects:

```
parse: function (response) {
    return response.objects;
}
```

The possible 2nd issue is that when a Collection.fetch() completes, the event it emits is not a `change` event, but a [`reset` event](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-events).  So, if you want your view to re-render when the fetch completes, you need to bind to `reset` not `change`.

Comment: Yes, I am using backbone-tastypie.js to override the parse function and others... I have changed the event to reset and it works on my server but not on jsfiddle. Is the code well-structured?